# bat file not updating the xml file

Tags: windows, batch-file, sed, cmd

I have written a bat, like the one below to update an xml tag, but it is not updating the xml file.

```
@echo off
SET PREFIX=ROOM107-
SET SUFFIX=\Admin
SET /P PCNAME1=Please enter your desired NUMBER:
SET PCNAME=%PREFIX%%PCNAME1%%SUFFIX%
$ sed 's#\<UserId>Admin</UserId># <UserId>%PCNAME%</UserId>#' Test.xml
```

The `UserId` should be updated to `ROOM107-01\Admin`.

Comment: ...and what is the question?

Comment: this is not updating the xml

Comment: Seems you are confusing [tag:batch-file] with [tag:bash]; the `$` syntax does not work in batch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding `-i` and double quotes it should work

```
@echo off
SET PREFIX=ROOM107-
SET SUFFIX=\Admin
SET /P PCNAME1=Please enter your desired NUMBER:
SET PCNAME=%PREFIX%%PCNAME1%%SUFFIX%

sed -i "s#<UserId>Admin</UserId>#<UserId>%PCNAME%</UserId>#" Test.xml
```

Comment: Also there was a small syntax issue in the  last line. it worked when I used it this way.  
 sed -i -e 's/<userid>Admin<\/userid>/<userid>%PCNAME%<\/userid>/' Test.xml